# SSRS reporting report designer

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report, expression, designer

I have a problem with times conversion. 
In my database, I have `2018-08-20 08:30:11.000 PM` and I can't change this format.

When I use `=Fields!DateTime.Value`, I display the date like this (it's only example).

[image: example photo]

But I want to display it in this way (date is ok) `2018-08-20 20:30:11`. 
I thought about searching this value and when it will be PM then add 12 to hour but it doesnt work... I have no more ideas...

```
=Format(Fields!DateTime.Value,"MM/dd/yyyy") & Environment.NewLine & iif (Fields!DateTimeValue="PM"), Format(Fields!DtTmStart.Value="HH+12:mm:ss")
```

Could somebody help me? Please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following expression should give you what you need...

```
=Format(Fields!DateTime.Value,"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Note the upper case HH, this gives 24 hour format (hh = 12 hour format)

Comment: No it didnt work I checked it....
When it is 2:40:01 PM and I want to 14:40:01
your advice gives me 2:40:01 . Only without PM and nothing more. 
My problem is how I should convert "2" on "14"

Comment: What date format are you seeing if you use the expression?

Try adding a new textbox and setting the expression of that textbox to 

`=Format(now(),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`

This should give you the current date/time in the format you want. If this works, but does not work fro your column then there might be a problem with the format of the date in your dataset. I've just checked my answer and it is the correct format (other than I used `/` instead of `'`).

Comment: Hey..My fault :) It works. I dont know what i did before.. Thank you!